# How to get EditText to not suggest text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText that I need to not suggest texts as user types. But I can't seem to get that to work. Here is the code

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: I don't think it matters but my EditText is in a dialog/modal

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with

```
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: hey congs.. but I thought you were using EditText for email. isn't it?